# How do I debug an angular 2 navigateToHome failure

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My angular2 app used to load a new page when navigateToHome was called via a button click.  I made some minor changes to the html and now it silently fails to load the home page when the button is clicked.  I suspect that I have introduced  some problem in the component tree but can't find it via code inspection of my changes. The typescript compiler makes no complaints.  Nothing shows up in the Chrome developer tools console.  Ideally I'd walk through the gradual loading of the component tree to see which component fails to load.  Or have some output to the console that shows the loading order and when it fails.

Comment: This is going to be very difficult to help you with without seeing any code.

Comment: I'm hoping for general techniques to watch the "loading" of the html component tree.  The app I inherited has over 20 components in the tree.  I can say that the breaking changes consist of removing some blanks lines between table tags, adding some number filters and adding some class= attributes to some tr and td tags.

Answer (score -1):

Check your module class and make sure you didn't forget to add declarations/import statements for the component that's not loaded.